# Add missing days till the end of the each month to dataframe Pandas using last value

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataframe with countries and their currency values for each month.

**Each value is only for the first day of the month.**

| Currency_Name | ISO_Code | Base_Currency | Decimal_Points | Date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan Afghani | AFN | USD | xx.xx | 2021-01-01 | 1.15000 |
| Albania Lek | ALL | USD | xxx | 2021-01-01 | 11.00000 |
| Algerian Dinar | DZD | USD | xx.x | 2021-01-01 | 112.30000 |

I would like to add missing days for each month with the value of the first day, so it could look like this for Afghanistan Afghani

| Currency_Name | ISO_Code | Base_Currency | Decimal_Points | Date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan Afghani | AFN | USD | xx.xx | 2021-01-01 | 1.15000 |
| Afghanistan Afghani | AFN | USD | xxx | 2021-01-02 | 1.150000 |
| Afghanistan Afghani | AFN | USD | xx.x | 2021-01-03 | 1.15000 |
| Afghanistan Afghani | AFN | USD | xx.x | 2021-01-04 | 1.15000 |
| - | - | - | - | - | - |
| Afghanistan Afghani | AFN | USD | xx.x | 2021-01-31 | 1.15000 |

and so on for each country and for each month

I tried this code

`df.set_index('Date').asfreq('D', method='ffill').reset_index()`

however it gives me an error

ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit

Could you please help?

Here is an updated input as dictionary:

pd.DataFrame(df.to_dict())

{'Currency_Name': {0: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1: 'Albania Lek', 2: 'Algerian Dinar', 131: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 132: 'Albania Lek', 133: 'Algerian Dinar', 262: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 263: 'Albania Lek', 264: 'Algerian Dinar', 393: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 394: 'Albania Lek', 395: 'Algerian Dinar', 524: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 525: 'Albania Lek', 526: 'Algerian Dinar', 655: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 656: 'Albania Lek', 657: 'Algerian Dinar', 786: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 787: 'Albania Lek', 788: 'Algerian Dinar', 917: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 918: 'Albania Lek', 919: 'Algerian Dinar', 1048: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1049: 'Albania Lek', 1050: 'Algerian Dinar', 1179: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1180: 'Albania Lek', 1181: 'Algerian Dinar', 1310: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1311: 'Albania Lek', 1312: 'Algerian Dinar', 1441: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1442: 'Albania Lek', 1443: 'Algerian Dinar', 1572: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1573: 'Albania Lek', 1574: 'Algerian Dinar', 1703: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1704: 'Albania Lek', 1705: 'Algerian Dinar', 1834: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1835: 'Albania Lek', 1836: 'Algerian Dinar', 1965: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1966: 'Albania Lek', 1967: 'Algerian Dinar', 2096: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2097: 'Albania Lek', 2098: 'Algerian Dinar', 2227: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2228: 'Albania Lek', 2229: 'Algerian Dinar', 2358: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2359: 'Albania Lek', 2360: 'Algerian Dinar', 2489: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2490: 'Albania Lek', 2491: 'Algerian Dinar', 2620: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2621: 'Albania Lek', 2622: 'Algerian Dinar', 2751: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2752: 'Albania Lek', 2753: 'Algerian Dinar', 2882: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2883: 'Albania Lek', 2884: 'Algerian Dinar', 3013: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 3014: 'Albania Lek', 3015: 'Algerian Dinar', 3144: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 3145: 'Albania Lek', 3146: 'Algerian Dinar', 3275: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 3276: 'Albania Lek', 3277: 'Algerian Dinar'}, 'ISO_Code': {0: 'AFN', 1: 'ALL', 2: 'DZD', 131: 'AFN', 132: 'ALL', 133: 'DZD', 262: 'AFN', 263: 'ALL', 264: 'DZD', 393: 'AFN', 394: 'ALL', 395: 'DZD', 524: 'AFN', 525: 'ALL', 526: 'DZD', 655: 'AFN', 656: 'ALL', 657: 'DZD', 786: 'AFN', 787: 'ALL', 788: 'DZD', 917: 'AFN', 918: 'ALL', 919: 'DZD', 1048: 'AFN', 1049: 'ALL', 1050: 'DZD', 1179: 'AFN', 1180: 'ALL', 1181: 'DZD', 1310: 'AFN', 1311: 'ALL', 1312: 'DZD', 1441: 'AFN', 1442: 'ALL', 1443: 'DZD', 1572: 'AFN', 1573: 'ALL', 1574: 'DZD', 1703: 'AFN', 1704: 'ALL', 1705: 'DZD', 1834: 'AFN', 1835: 'ALL', 1836: 'DZD', 1965: 'AFN', 1966: 'ALL', 1967: 'DZD', 2096: 'AFN', 2097: 'ALL', 2098: 'DZD', 2227: 'AFN', 2228: 'ALL', 2229: 'DZD', 2358: 'AFN', 2359: 'ALL', 2360: 'DZD', 2489: 'AFN', 2490: 'ALL', 2491: 'DZD', 2620: 'AFN', 2621: 'ALL', 2622: 'DZD', 2751: 'AFN', 2752: 'ALL', 2753: 'DZD', 2882: 'AFN', 2883: 'ALL', 2884: 'DZD', 3013: 'AFN', 3014: 'ALL', 3015: 'DZD', 3144: 'AFN', 3145: 'ALL', 3146: 'DZD', 3275: 'AFN', 3276: 'ALL', 3277: 'DZD'}, 'Base_Currency': {0: 'USD', 1: 'USD', 2: 'USD', 131: 'USD', 132: 'USD', 133: 'USD', 262: 'USD', 263: 'USD', 264: 'USD', 393: 'USD', 394: 'USD', 395: 'USD', 524: 'USD', 525: 'USD', 526: 'USD', 655: 'USD', 656: 'USD', 657: 'USD', 786: 'USD', 787: 'USD', 788: 'USD', 917: 'USD', 918: 'USD', 919: 'USD', 1048: 'USD', 1049: 'USD', 1050: 'USD', 1179: 'USD', 1180: 'USD', 1181: 'USD', 1310: 'USD', 1311: 'USD', 1312: 'USD', 1441: 'USD', 1442: 'USD', 1443: 'USD', 1572: 'USD', 1573: 'USD', 1574: 'USD', 1703: 'USD', 1704: 'USD', 1705: 'USD', 1834: 'USD', 1835: 'USD', 1836: 'USD', 1965: 'USD', 1966: 'USD', 1967: 'USD', 2096: 'USD', 2097: 'USD', 2098: 'USD', 2227: 'USD', 2228: 'USD', 2229: 'USD', 2358: 'USD', 2359: 'USD', 2360: 'USD', 2489: 'USD', 2490: 'USD', 2491: 'USD', 2620: 'USD', 2621: 'USD', 2622: 'USD', 2751: 'USD', 2752: 'USD', 2753: 'USD', 2882: 'USD', 2883: 'USD', 2884: 'USD', 3013: 'USD', 3014: 'USD', 3015: 'USD', 3144: 'USD', 3145: 'USD', 3146: 'USD', 3275: 'USD', 3276: 'USD', 3277: 'USD'}, 'Decimal_Points': {0: 'xx.xx', 1: 'xxx', 2: 'xx.x', 131: 'xx.xx', 132: 'xxx', 133: 'xx.x', 262: 'xx.xx', 263: 'xxx', 264: 'xx.x', 393: 'xx.xx', 394: 'xxx', 395: 'xx.x', 524: 'xx.xx', 525: 'xxx', 526: 'xx.x', 655: 'xx.xx', 656: 'xxx', 657: 'xx.x', 786: 'xx.xx', 787: 'xxx', 788: 'xx.x', 917: 'xx.xx', 918: 'xxx', 919: 'xx.x', 1048: 'xx.xx', 1049: 'xxx', 1050: 'xx.x', 1179: 'xx.xx', 1180: 'xxx', 1181: 'xx.x', 1310: 'xx.xx', 1311: 'xxx', 1312: 'xx.x', 1441: 'xx.xx', 1442: 'xxx', 1443: 'xx.x', 1572: 'xx.xx', 1573: 'xxx', 1574: 'xx.x', 1703: 'xx.xx', 1704: 'xxx', 1705: 'xx.x', 1834: 'xx.xx', 1835: 'xxx', 1836: 'xx.x', 1965: 'xx.xx', 1966: 'xxx', 1967: 'xx.x', 2096: 'xx.xx', 2097: 'xxx', 2098: 'xx.x', 2227: 'xx.xx', 2228: 'xxx', 2229: 'xx.x', 2358: 'xx.xx', 2359: 'xxx', 2360: 'xx.x', 2489: 'xx.xx', 2490: 'xxx', 2491: 'xx.x', 2620: 'xx.xx', 2621: 'xxx', 2622: 'xx.x', 2751: 'xx.xx', 2752: 'xxx', 2753: 'xx.x', 2882: 'xx.xx', 2883: 'xxx', 2884: 'xx.x', 3013: 'xx.xx', 3014: 'xxx', 3015: 'xx.x', 3144: 'xx.xx', 3145: 'xxx', 3146: 'xx.x', 3275: 'xx.xx', 3276: 'xxx', 3277: 'xx.x'}, 'Date': {0: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), 131: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'), 132: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'), 133: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'), 262: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'), 263: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'), 264: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'), 393: Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:00:00'), 394: Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:00:00'), 395: Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:00:00'), 524: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'), 525: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'), 526: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'), 655: Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 656: Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 657: Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 786: Timestamp('2021-07-01 00:00:00'), 787: Timestamp('2021-07-01 00:00:00'), 788: Timestamp('2021-07-01 00:00:00'), 917: Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'), 918: Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'), 919: Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'), 1048: Timestamp('2021-09-01 00:00:00'), 1049: Timestamp('2021-09-01 00:00:00'), 1050: Timestamp('2021-09-01 00:00:00'), 1179: Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 1180: Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 1181: Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 1310: Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 1311: Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 1312: Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 1441: Timestamp('2021-12-01 00:00:00'), 1442: Timestamp('2021-12-01 00:00:00'), 1443: Timestamp('2021-12-01 00:00:00'), 1572: Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00'), 1573: Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00'), 1574: Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00'), 1703: Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'), 1704: Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'), 1705: Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'), 1834: Timestamp('2022-03-01 00:00:00'), 1835: Timestamp('2022-03-01 00:00:00'), 1836: Timestamp('2022-03-01 00:00:00'), 1965: Timestamp('2022-04-01 00:00:00'), 1966: Timestamp('2022-04-01 00:00:00'), 1967: Timestamp('2022-04-01 00:00:00'), 2096: Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), 2097: Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), 2098: Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), 2227: Timestamp('2022-06-01 00:00:00'), 2228: Timestamp('2022-06-01 00:00:00'), 2229: Timestamp('2022-06-01 00:00:00'), 2358: Timestamp('2022-07-01 00:00:00'), 2359: Timestamp('2022-07-01 00:00:00'), 2360: Timestamp('2022-07-01 00:00:00'), 2489: Timestamp('2022-08-01 00:00:00'), 2490: Timestamp('2022-08-01 00:00:00'), 2491: Timestamp('2022-08-01 00:00:00'), 2620: Timestamp('2022-09-01 00:00:00'), 2621: Timestamp('2022-09-01 00:00:00'), 2622: Timestamp('2022-09-01 00:00:00'), 2751: Timestamp('2022-10-01 00:00:00'), 2752: Timestamp('2022-10-01 00:00:00'), 2753: Timestamp('2022-10-01 00:00:00'), 2882: Timestamp('2022-11-01 00:00:00'), 2883: Timestamp('2022-11-01 00:00:00'), 2884: Timestamp('2022-11-01 00:00:00'), 3013: Timestamp('2022-12-01 00:00:00'), 3014: Timestamp('2022-12-01 00:00:00'), 3015: Timestamp('2022-12-01 00:00:00'), 3144: Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00'), 3145: Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00'), 3146: Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00'), 3275: Timestamp('2023-02-01 00:00:00'), 3276: Timestamp('2023-02-01 00:00:00'), 3277: Timestamp('2023-02-01 00:00:00')}, 'value': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 131: 1, 132: 1, 133: 1, 262: 1, 263: 1, 264: 1, 393: 1, 394: 1, 395: 1, 524: 1, 525: 1, 526: 1, 655: 1, 656: 1, 657: 1, 786: 1, 787: 1, 788: 1, 917: 1, 918: 1, 919: 1, 1048: 1, 1049: 1, 1050: 1, 1179: 1, 1180: 1, 1181: 1, 1310: 1, 1311: 1, 1312: 1, 1441: 1, 1442: 1, 1443: 1, 1572: 1, 1573: 1, 1574: 1, 1703: 1, 1704: 1, 1705: 1, 1834: 1, 1835: 1, 1836: 1, 1965: 1, 1966: 1, 1967: 1, 2096: 1, 2097: 1, 2098: 1, 2227: 1, 2228: 1, 2229: 1, 2358: 1, 2359: 1, 2360: 1, 2489: 1, 2490: 1, 2491: 1, 2620: 1, 2621: 1, 2622: 1, 2751: 1, 2752: 1, 2753: 1, 2882: 1, 2883: 1, 2884: 1, 3013: 1, 3014: 1, 3015: 1, 3144: 1, 3145: 1, 3146: 1, 3275: 1, 3276: 1, 3277: 1}}

Comment: groupby the country first then use `.resample`

Comment: @It_is_Chris I have this error ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit 

because my dates are not unique and it repeats for each country is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you update your sample dataframe to represent a repeated country and date?

Answer (score 0):

does this help?

```
import pandas as pd

# Load data into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('currency_data.csv')

# Convert date column to datetime type
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Set Date column as index and group by Currency_Name and Month
df = df.set_index('Date')
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Currency_Name', pd.Grouper(freq='M')])

# Fill missing days with the value of the first day of the month
df_filled = df_grouped.apply(lambda x: x.resample('D').ffill())

# Reset the index and drop the extra month level
df_filled = df_filled.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()

# Save the output to a new CSV file
df_filled.to_csv('currency_data_filled.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: still got this error ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit
after this 


`df_filled = df_grouped.apply(lambda x: x.resample('D').ffill())`

probably because my dates are not unique and it repeats for each country

is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

## Update

```
# sort values first
df = df.sort_values(['Currency_Name', 'Date'])
# find the month end which will become the index later
me = df['Date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
# get the number of unique currency names
n = df['Currency_Name'].nunique()
# reassign the first currency name dates to the month start
me.iloc[:n] = me.iloc[:n] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1)
# set the index
df.index = me
# groupby and resample
new_df = df.drop(columns='Date').groupby('Currency_Name').resample('D').ffill().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

                  Currency_Name ISO_Code Base_Currency Decimal_Points  value
Date                                                                        
2021-01-01  Afghanistan Afghani      AFN           USD          xx.xx      1
2021-01-02  Afghanistan Afghani      AFN           USD          xx.xx      1
2021-01-03  Afghanistan Afghani      AFN           USD          xx.xx      1
2021-01-04  Afghanistan Afghani      AFN           USD          xx.xx      1
2021-01-05  Afghanistan Afghani      AFN           USD          xx.xx      1
...                         ...      ...           ...            ...    ...
2023-02-24       Algerian Dinar      DZD           USD           xx.x      1
2023-02-25       Algerian Dinar      DZD           USD           xx.x      1
2023-02-26       Algerian Dinar      DZD           USD           xx.x      1
2023-02-27       Algerian Dinar      DZD           USD           xx.x      1
2023-02-28       Algerian Dinar      DZD           USD           xx.x      1

[2307 rows x 5 columns]
```

You can try the following

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

# your sample data
d = {'Currency_Name': {0: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1: 'Albania Lek', 2: 'Algerian Dinar', 131: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 132: 'Albania Lek', 133: 'Algerian Dinar', 262: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 263: 'Albania Lek', 264: 'Algerian Dinar', 393: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 394: 'Albania Lek', 395: 'Algerian Dinar', 524: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 525: 'Albania Lek', 526: 'Algerian Dinar', 655: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 656: 'Albania Lek', 657: 'Algerian Dinar', 786: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 787: 'Albania Lek', 788: 'Algerian Dinar', 917: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 918: 'Albania Lek', 919: 'Algerian Dinar', 1048: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1049: 'Albania Lek', 1050: 'Algerian Dinar', 1179: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1180: 'Albania Lek', 1181: 'Algerian Dinar', 1310: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1311: 'Albania Lek', 1312: 'Algerian Dinar', 1441: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1442: 'Albania Lek', 1443: 'Algerian Dinar', 1572: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1573: 'Albania Lek', 1574: 'Algerian Dinar', 1703: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1704: 'Albania Lek', 1705: 'Algerian Dinar', 1834: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1835: 'Albania Lek', 1836: 'Algerian Dinar', 1965: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 1966: 'Albania Lek', 1967: 'Algerian Dinar', 2096: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2097: 'Albania Lek', 2098: 'Algerian Dinar', 2227: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2228: 'Albania Lek', 2229: 'Algerian Dinar', 2358: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2359: 'Albania Lek', 2360: 'Algerian Dinar', 2489: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2490: 'Albania Lek', 2491: 'Algerian Dinar', 2620: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2621: 'Albania Lek', 2622: 'Algerian Dinar', 2751: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2752: 'Albania Lek', 2753: 'Algerian Dinar', 2882: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 2883: 'Albania Lek', 2884: 'Algerian Dinar', 3013: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 3014: 'Albania Lek', 3015: 'Algerian Dinar', 3144: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 3145: 'Albania Lek', 3146: 'Algerian Dinar', 3275: 'Afghanistan Afghani', 3276: 'Albania Lek', 3277: 'Algerian Dinar'}, 'ISO_Code': {0: 'AFN', 1: 'ALL', 2: 'DZD', 131: 'AFN', 132: 'ALL', 133: 'DZD', 262: 'AFN', 263: 'ALL', 264: 'DZD', 393: 'AFN', 394: 'ALL', 395: 'DZD', 524: 'AFN', 525: 'ALL', 526: 'DZD', 655: 'AFN', 656: 'ALL', 657: 'DZD', 786: 'AFN', 787: 'ALL', 788: 'DZD', 917: 'AFN', 918: 'ALL', 919: 'DZD', 1048: 'AFN', 1049: 'ALL', 1050: 'DZD', 1179: 'AFN', 1180: 'ALL', 1181: 'DZD', 1310: 'AFN', 1311: 'ALL', 1312: 'DZD', 1441: 'AFN', 1442: 'ALL', 1443: 'DZD', 1572: 'AFN', 1573: 'ALL', 1574: 'DZD', 1703: 'AFN', 1704: 'ALL', 1705: 'DZD', 1834: 'AFN', 1835: 'ALL', 1836: 'DZD', 1965: 'AFN', 1966: 'ALL', 1967: 'DZD', 2096: 'AFN', 2097: 'ALL', 2098: 'DZD', 2227: 'AFN', 2228: 'ALL', 2229: 'DZD', 2358: 'AFN', 2359: 'ALL', 2360: 'DZD', 2489: 'AFN', 2490: 'ALL', 2491: 'DZD', 2620: 'AFN', 2621: 'ALL', 2622: 'DZD', 2751: 'AFN', 2752: 'ALL', 2753: 'DZD', 2882: 'AFN', 2883: 'ALL', 2884: 'DZD', 3013: 'AFN', 3014: 'ALL', 3015: 'DZD', 3144: 'AFN', 3145: 'ALL', 3146: 'DZD', 3275: 'AFN', 3276: 'ALL', 3277: 'DZD'}, 'Base_Currency': {0: 'USD', 1: 'USD', 2: 'USD', 131: 'USD', 132: 'USD', 133: 'USD', 262: 'USD', 263: 'USD', 264: 'USD', 393: 'USD', 394: 'USD', 395: 'USD', 524: 'USD', 525: 'USD', 526: 'USD', 655: 'USD', 656: 'USD', 657: 'USD', 786: 'USD', 787: 'USD', 788: 'USD', 917: 'USD', 918: 'USD', 919: 'USD', 1048: 'USD', 1049: 'USD', 1050: 'USD', 1179: 'USD', 1180: 'USD', 1181: 'USD', 1310: 'USD', 1311: 'USD', 1312: 'USD', 1441: 'USD', 1442: 'USD', 1443: 'USD', 1572: 'USD', 1573: 'USD', 1574: 'USD', 1703: 'USD', 1704: 'USD', 1705: 'USD', 1834: 'USD', 1835: 'USD', 1836: 'USD', 1965: 'USD', 1966: 'USD', 1967: 'USD', 2096: 'USD', 2097: 'USD', 2098: 'USD', 2227: 'USD', 2228: 'USD', 2229: 'USD', 2358: 'USD', 2359: 'USD', 2360: 'USD', 2489: 'USD', 2490: 'USD', 2491: 'USD', 2620: 'USD', 2621: 'USD', 2622: 'USD', 2751: 'USD', 2752: 'USD', 2753: 'USD', 2882: 'USD', 2883: 'USD', 2884: 'USD', 3013: 'USD', 3014: 'USD', 3015: 'USD', 3144: 'USD', 3145: 'USD', 3146: 'USD', 3275: 'USD', 3276: 'USD', 3277: 'USD'}, 'Decimal_Points': {0: 'xx.xx', 1: 'xxx', 2: 'xx.x', 131: 'xx.xx', 132: 'xxx', 133: 'xx.x', 262: 'xx.xx', 263: 'xxx', 264: 'xx.x', 393: 'xx.xx', 394: 'xxx', 395: 'xx.x', 524: 'xx.xx', 525: 'xxx', 526: 'xx.x', 655: 'xx.xx', 656: 'xxx', 657: 'xx.x', 786: 'xx.xx', 787: 'xxx', 788: 'xx.x', 917: 'xx.xx', 918: 'xxx', 919: 'xx.x', 1048: 'xx.xx', 1049: 'xxx', 1050: 'xx.x', 1179: 'xx.xx', 1180: 'xxx', 1181: 'xx.x', 1310: 'xx.xx', 1311: 'xxx', 1312: 'xx.x', 1441: 'xx.xx', 1442: 'xxx', 1443: 'xx.x', 1572: 'xx.xx', 1573: 'xxx', 1574: 'xx.x', 1703: 'xx.xx', 1704: 'xxx', 1705: 'xx.x', 1834: 'xx.xx', 1835: 'xxx', 1836: 'xx.x', 1965: 'xx.xx', 1966: 'xxx', 1967: 'xx.x', 2096: 'xx.xx', 2097: 'xxx', 2098: 'xx.x', 2227: 'xx.xx', 2228: 'xxx', 2229: 'xx.x', 2358: 'xx.xx', 2359: 'xxx', 2360: 'xx.x', 2489: 'xx.xx', 2490: 'xxx', 2491: 'xx.x', 2620: 'xx.xx', 2621: 'xxx', 2622: 'xx.x', 2751: 'xx.xx', 2752: 'xxx', 2753: 'xx.x', 2882: 'xx.xx', 2883: 'xxx', 2884: 'xx.x', 3013: 'xx.xx', 3014: 'xxx', 3015: 'xx.x', 3144: 'xx.xx', 3145: 'xxx', 3146: 'xx.x', 3275: 'xx.xx', 3276: 'xxx', 3277: 'xx.x'}, 'Date': {0: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), 131: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'), 132: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'), 133: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'), 262: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'), 263: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'), 264: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'), 393: Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:00:00'), 394: Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:00:00'), 395: Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:00:00'), 524: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'), 525: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'), 526: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'), 655: Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 656: Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 657: Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 786: Timestamp('2021-07-01 00:00:00'), 787: Timestamp('2021-07-01 00:00:00'), 788: Timestamp('2021-07-01 00:00:00'), 917: Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'), 918: Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'), 919: Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'), 1048: Timestamp('2021-09-01 00:00:00'), 1049: Timestamp('2021-09-01 00:00:00'), 1050: Timestamp('2021-09-01 00:00:00'), 1179: Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 1180: Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 1181: Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 1310: Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 1311: Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 1312: Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 1441: Timestamp('2021-12-01 00:00:00'), 1442: Timestamp('2021-12-01 00:00:00'), 1443: Timestamp('2021-12-01 00:00:00'), 1572: Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00'), 1573: Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00'), 1574: Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00'), 1703: Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'), 1704: Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'), 1705: Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'), 1834: Timestamp('2022-03-01 00:00:00'), 1835: Timestamp('2022-03-01 00:00:00'), 1836: Timestamp('2022-03-01 00:00:00'), 1965: Timestamp('2022-04-01 00:00:00'), 1966: Timestamp('2022-04-01 00:00:00'), 1967: Timestamp('2022-04-01 00:00:00'), 2096: Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), 2097: Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), 2098: Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), 2227: Timestamp('2022-06-01 00:00:00'), 2228: Timestamp('2022-06-01 00:00:00'), 2229: Timestamp('2022-06-01 00:00:00'), 2358: Timestamp('2022-07-01 00:00:00'), 2359: Timestamp('2022-07-01 00:00:00'), 2360: Timestamp('2022-07-01 00:00:00'), 2489: Timestamp('2022-08-01 00:00:00'), 2490: Timestamp('2022-08-01 00:00:00'), 2491: Timestamp('2022-08-01 00:00:00'), 2620: Timestamp('2022-09-01 00:00:00'), 2621: Timestamp('2022-09-01 00:00:00'), 2622: Timestamp('2022-09-01 00:00:00'), 2751: Timestamp('2022-10-01 00:00:00'), 2752: Timestamp('2022-10-01 00:00:00'), 2753: Timestamp('2022-10-01 00:00:00'), 2882: Timestamp('2022-11-01 00:00:00'), 2883: Timestamp('2022-11-01 00:00:00'), 2884: Timestamp('2022-11-01 00:00:00'), 3013: Timestamp('2022-12-01 00:00:00'), 3014: Timestamp('2022-12-01 00:00:00'), 3015: Timestamp('2022-12-01 00:00:00'), 3144: Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00'), 3145: Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00'), 3146: Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00'), 3275: Timestamp('2023-02-01 00:00:00'), 3276: Timestamp('2023-02-01 00:00:00'), 3277: Timestamp('2023-02-01 00:00:00')}, 'value': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 131: 1, 132: 1, 133: 1, 262: 1, 263: 1, 264: 1, 393: 1, 394: 1, 395: 1, 524: 1, 525: 1, 526: 1, 655: 1, 656: 1, 657: 1, 786: 1, 787: 1, 788: 1, 917: 1, 918: 1, 919: 1, 1048: 1, 1049: 1, 1050: 1, 1179: 1, 1180: 1, 1181: 1, 1310: 1, 1311: 1, 1312: 1, 1441: 1, 1442: 1, 1443: 1, 1572: 1, 1573: 1, 1574: 1, 1703: 1, 1704: 1, 1705: 1, 1834: 1, 1835: 1, 1836: 1, 1965: 1, 1966: 1, 1967: 1, 2096: 1, 2097: 1, 2098: 1, 2227: 1, 2228: 1, 2229: 1, 2358: 1, 2359: 1, 2360: 1, 2489: 1, 2490: 1, 2491: 1, 2620: 1, 2621: 1, 2622: 1, 2751: 1, 2752: 1, 2753: 1, 2882: 1, 2883: 1, 2884: 1, 3013: 1, 3014: 1, 3015: 1, 3144: 1, 3145: 1, 3146: 1, 3275: 1, 3276: 1, 3277: 1}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# set the index to Date, groupby the currency name and the resample to the day
# forward fill the missing data and reset the index
new_df = df.set_index('Date').groupby(['Currency_Name']).resample('D').ffill().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)



                  Currency_Name ISO_Code Base_Currency Decimal_Points  value
Date                                                                        
2021-01-01  Afghanistan Afghani      AFN           USD          xx.xx      1
2021-01-02  Afghanistan Afghani      AFN           USD          xx.xx      1
2021-01-03  Afghanistan Afghani      AFN           USD          xx.xx      1
2021-01-04  Afghanistan Afghani      AFN           USD          xx.xx      1
2021-01-05  Afghanistan Afghani      AFN           USD          xx.xx      1
...                         ...      ...           ...            ...    ...
2023-01-28       Algerian Dinar      DZD           USD           xx.x      1
2023-01-29       Algerian Dinar      DZD           USD           xx.x      1
2023-01-30       Algerian Dinar      DZD           USD           xx.x      1
2023-01-31       Algerian Dinar      DZD           USD           xx.x      1
2023-02-01       Algerian Dinar      DZD           USD           xx.x      1

[2286 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: thank you, and do you know why it doesn't fill values for the last month? like current month is 2023-02-01, but it still the same

Comment: That is because resample will go from the first index value to the last, otherwise there is no way indicate when the resample should stop. To get around that see the update.

Comment: it's strange, but for some currencies it still the same. 
I added this line 
new_df['Date'] = new_df.index

to get Date in a dataframe, because I need it and in case of Afghanistan Afghani the last date is still 2023-01-31.

Does it work in your case?

Comment: @2837a It works for me: `new_df.reset_index().groupby('Currency_Name')['Date'].last()` returns `Currency_Name
Afghanistan Afghani   2023-02-28
Albania Lek           2023-02-28
Algerian Dinar        2023-02-28`

Comment: Ok, I tested separately and it works when it's one currency. But when there are more  than that, I'm missing some of them. Anyway, I noticed that for the last month (which is Feb 2023) it assigns value in the wrong way. First, it takes the last value from Jan and make a copy till the 27 Feb. Then for the last day (28 Feb) it has the right value. Do you know if there is any workaround here? I can not update my initial thread for some reason with the new sample.